# How to call EJB A in EJB B from EJB C?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

i have 3 ejb bean

**FactoryEquip**

```
@Local
public interface FactoryEquip {

    List<Equip> findAll();

}
```

**FactoryGame**

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class FactoryGame {
    @EJB FactoryEquip fEquip;

    public void findAll(){
        List<Equip> eq= fEquip.findAll();
    } 
}
```

**Websocket**

```
@Singleton
@ServerEndpoint("/socket")
public class Websocket {

    @EJB FactoryGame fGame;

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session){

             //this code work fine
             fGame.findAll();

             //this code not work (error)
             List<Equip> eq= fGame.fEquip.findAll();

         return "ok";
    }

   //another websocket function ...
```

when websocket receive message, it will give error because of NullPointerExceptionerror,

fEquip is not null and work fine in the line

```
fGame.findAll();
```

but fEquip is null in the line

```
List<Equip> eq= fGame.fEquip.findAll();
```

how to fix this ?

forgive my english, thanks

Comment: why i got down vote ? please tell the reason before give a down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this - the container wraps EJBs into a proxy that implements the same public interface but is not actually your actual EJB class.  This is why you get the NPE.  Never access fields of other EJBs directly ,always use method invocation.  On a related note, it's not a good programming practice to `chain.calls.like.this()`.

Comment: The right thing to do would be not accessing the EJBs like this.